# Filter in LoadProperty or Include

Tags: entity-framework-4

LoadProperty or Include retrieves all relationated rows from a principal entity. How can I filter the rows retrieved from a LoadProperty call? I would want not to do a post-processing of data recover from DB.

My case is something like this

```
public Expression<Func<TipoReforma, bool>> predicadoFiltroIdioma(String filtro)
    {
    return x => x.DetalleTipoReforma.Any(y=>filtro.Contains(y.Idioma.idioma));
    }


IEnumerable<T> resultado = objectSet.Where<T>(predicadoFiltroIdioma("en");
Contexto.LoadProperty(resultado.ToList()[0], "DetalleTipoReforma");
```

I want only "TipoReforma" but related information should be only those which idioma is "x".

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

Neither `LoadProperty` or `Include` support filtering = they always load all related entities. You must use different approach. You can try to use `CreateSourceQuery`. Something like:

```
var data = ((EntityCollection<TipoReforma>)resultado.ToList[0].DetalleTipReforma)
                .CreateSourceQuery().OrderBy(predicadoFiltroIdioma).ToList();
```

It should also fill your navigation property in the principal entity. Also make sure that lazy loading is turned off before you execute this code.